# Data insert as null through from the cursor in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a stored procedure for data insert from a cursor in mysql. Once  the data were inserted to the table it is inserted as null.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Data_Insert_JB_Securities`()
Begin 

declare title varchar(200);
DECLARE V_title varchar(200) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DEClARE cursor_JB_Security CURSOR FOR select title from JB_Security_Detials_insert ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;


OPEN cursor_JB_Security;

get_title: LOOP 

FETCH cursor_JB_Security INTO V_title;

IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_title;
 END IF;


insert into JB_Security_Detials_test(title)
value(V_title);

END LOOP get_title;

close cursor_JB_Security;

END
```

Comment: Can you post `JB_Security_Detials_insert` table structure and some sample data?.

Comment: I have created this table as testing purpose.

Comment: create table JB_Security_Detials_insert(
title varchar(200))                                                                                              sample data  - any varchar values

Comment: Comment `title` variable. `/* declare title varchar(200); */`. See [13.6.4.2 Local Variable Scope and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html) and [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It's Working fine.